# Ways of getting video out of the Pi camera

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspicam

I wonder what are all the methods of getting video out of the Pi camera.

Reading this: http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_Camera

And this:https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/

And this:https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/

It seems like there are currently the 4 methods of getting video out of the Pi camera

- Native raspivid shell command
- UV4L interface
- V4l2 interface
- Picamera Python application

Have I missed anything?
I'm trying to get multi camera working simultaneously, and so far raspivid & UV4L have being tested to work. I wonder if someone could give me some experiences so I could speed up the process and pick the best approach.

Comment: What you're ultimately hoping to do with the video, how you're going to trigger the capture, what settings you need to control during recording will all affect which interface is the best choice for your applications. More detail required.